# why retain of delegate is wrong what are all alternatives...?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, retain-cycle

I have one problem let assume A and B are 2 view controller from A user push to B view controller,In B user starts some download by creating object C(which is NSObject class) and sets B as delegate to C(assign),now user want  go back to A then dealloc of B calls object releases, C delegate fails to give call back(crashes).I want to get call and allow user to move to other view controller thats way i am retain the delegate in C class but retain of delegate is wrong ...

```
what are all solutions ...
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how to accept answers.... i tried its telling it requires minimum 15 reputations to vote answers...

Comment: @jeeva http://stackoverflow.com/faq - see section on "how to Ask Questions"

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. You do not need the downloaded data. Solution: set the delegate to nil.
2. You need the data. Solution: You either set a new delegate that exists, or the delegate should make sure it will be around (f.e. by being a singleton)

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of an issue in your architecture: you're assigning the global task of background downloading to a view controller that may or may not be in memory.

If you want to be able to continue the download regardless of the presence of B, then:

1. Create a class "downloader" that takes care of downloading files (I believe you call it C in your example).
2. Such class should have a delegate of type "weak" so that if the original delegate goes away, the app won't crash (NOTE: this is only available if you use ARC). If you need to globally monitor the progress of your download, switch to `NSNotification` instead of delegate so that multiple object can monitor at the same time.
3. Initialize an instance of C somewhere else: either in A or before that.
4. Inject the instance of C into B so that B by creating a custom `init` method or a `@property`.